# Javascript Segmentation fault 11 on Mac

Tags: javascript, macos, terminal, segmentation-fault

Every time I try to use Javascript in Terminal (OSX Yosemite beta 3) using the jsc command, it gives me this:

> Segmentation fault: 11

This all started when I ran this code through the compiler:

```
var swap = function(array, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
    var temp = array[firstIndex];
    array[firstIndex] = array[secondIndex];
    array[secondIndex] = temp;
};

var moveBack = function(array, index) {
    for (var pos = 0; pos < index; pos ++){
        print(pos)
    }
};

// Array to test on
var array = [22, 11, 99, 88, 9, 7, 42];
moveBack(array, 3);
print(array);
```

Now anything that I run, including things that worked before, gets that error message. It also seemed to effect python in the same way, but I found some helpful help online for that.

Comment: When all else fails, reboot?